Calling the constructor of the super class in SuperCollider
I want to create a subclass of the gui class View. It needs to act like a view, so I need to ensure that I call View's constructors, but I don't know how to actually do this.
My class now is:
SplitHPanel : View {

    *new{|parent, bounds, leftPanel, rightPanel, dominant=\left|
        ^super.new(parent, bounds);
    }
}

This should, hopefully act exactly like a normal View, but doesn't.
For example:
(
j = SplitHPanel().background_(Color.rand);
j.toFrontAction = { "Something should have happened".postln};
j.front
)

This code block returns an instance of SplitHPanel with no errors, but it also doesn't open a window or run the action.
What incredibly fiddly detail am I missing?
